# MySQL query to select the max date for the relation table based on criteria at second level

Tags: mysql, redmine

Here is my [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/080a21/1)

Basically I have three tables, A issues, journals and journal details.
I would like to have in a single query the following way of representation.

```
id    | status_id | X |
90001 | 12 | NULL |
90002 | 12 | NULL |
90003 | 12 | 2015-01-06 |
90004 | 12 | 2015-01-09 |
```

The rule applied is for X is the max 'journals' created date at which the 'fixed_version_id' == 55 exists.

Please help.

Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you start by getting the details of all the journals that meet your requirement like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM journal_details
WHERE property = 'fixed_version_id' AND value = '55';
```

Then you can use those values to get the created date of the `journal` rows that meet this requirement:

```
SELECT j.issue_id, MAX(j.created_on) AS created_on
FROM journals j
JOIN journal_details jd ON jd.journal_id = j.id AND jd.property = 'fixed_version_id' AND jd.value = '55'
GROUP BY j.issue_id;
```

From these results, you can join in to get all `issues`. If you use an outer join, you'll get null for any journals that didn't meet the criteria:

```
SELECT i.id, i.status_id, tmp.created_on
FROM issues i
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT j.issue_id, MAX(j.created_on) AS created_on
  FROM journals j
  JOIN journal_details jd ON jd.journal_id = j.id AND jd.property = 'fixed_version_id' AND jd.value = '55'
  GROUP BY j.issue_id
) tmp ON tmp.issue_id = i.id;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/080a21/13) example.

Comment: Hi McAdam, Thank You for your reply, But your query gives me two rows in this case [Mutiple row for 90004](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/716bb/1)

Comment: @rupeshj That was my mistake, I didn't consider multiple rows. You said in your question you wanted the max date, in which case you just change the code to `MAX(j.created_on)` in the subquery and add a `GROUP BY` clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/716bb/5